# IntelliJ not correctly analyzing grpc-kotlin generated code

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, grpc, grpc-kotlin

I have followed the instructions here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/tree/master/compiler for Gradle, and everything is working fine, but IntelliJ is seeing errors in the generated code, even though when I run the application and manually write code I know would work it runs just fine.

[image: intellij error]

[image: intellij not seeing other source sets]

Comment: What the error is shown?

Comment: Could you show us you Gradle ?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov When I go to the file that contains that generated code IntelliJ finds hundreds of errors, probably the ones causing all the other errors are "Unresolved symbol" and "Cannot resolve symbol", where each of the source sets are not finding code from the other source sets.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense was disabled in one of the generated code files because of file size, causing all the others to have errors. I was able to increase the intellisense max file size and now everything works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).